# Stacked bar chart with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, charts

I'm trying to create stacked bar chart with HTML and CSS.

**Example 1**

This example shows stacked bars aligned to top. However, they should be aligned to bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/zw0vx388/

**Wrong solution**

I added `position: absolute; bottom: 0` to align bars to bottom. However, they overlap. They should be stacked one above another. Any other solution except flexbox (I must support IE9)?

http://jsfiddle.net/zw0vx388/1/

Comment: The easiest and most reliable way would be to add an extra div for padding on the top.

Comment: This is what @PeeHaa suggested http://jsfiddle.net/zw0vx388/2/

Comment: Agreed, best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Adding display:list-item; does your job.

```
.bar-container {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    display:list-item;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/82891kqL/

Comment: This only works because you're adding a bullet which shifts the column down just enough. Change the height of the chart to 400px and you'll see this didn't work.